# how to connect Raspberry Pi to windows database

Tags: raspbian

I am very new to Raspberry Pi, I have written a program in python and connection with PostgreSQL.

I am running python application on Raspberry Pi and my database is on Windows server in LAN.

Can anyone tell me how to connect the Python program on the Raspberry Pi with the PostgreSQL database on the Windows Server.

If I connect both in system in network then is it accessible.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Your question is not clear enough. What are you looking for? Network setting? Python code? Explanation?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [python postgres library](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/) you can do somehing like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="yourwindowsmachine.local.ip.address",database="yourDatabaseName", user="postgresUsername", password="postgresPassword")
```

Replace `yourwindowsmachine.local.ip.address` with the IP or a resolvable address to your windows machine.
Replace `yourDatabaseName` with the database name.
Replace `postgresUsername` and `postgresPassword` with the credentials to the postgres server.

This is the connection object for the postgres library, with the `host` parameter indicating that you are connecting to anothe host than the localhost.

On your Windows box, you need to make sure that if you are running windows firewall, you need to have the ports for postgres opened as well.

Comment: What is this? A command on a command line? On what command line?

Comment: @ingo it is python, as the OP wrote in his post